# class template evaluating to a function

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have the following code:

```
typedef Coord2d<double> dCoord;
typedef std::pair<dCoord, Color<double> > cdpair;
CircularBuffer<cdpair>  _path;

dCoord head()
{
  return _path.front().first(); // error here
}
```

`dCoord` is a class but I'm getting the following error:

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

I get the same error even when I'm not returning the value. Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

P.S.
`front()` returns an item of type `myPair`.

Comment: I do not know the class CircularBuffer. Does it have a member function called front? What does this function return? You should improve your code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`first` is a member, not a function:

```
return _path.front().first;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `first` on a `std::pair` is a member variable, which is in your case a `dCoord`, which, as the error says, does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments.

tl;dr: `std::pair::first` is a variable, not a function.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely answer is that `first` is the `first` member of `std::pair`. It is a public data member of type `dCoord`, not a function, and so it cannot be called as a function.

Try:

```
return _path.front().first;
```

Answer (score 1):

`first` and `second` are data members of `std::pair`, not member functions. Try this:

```
dCoord head()
{
    return _path.front().first;
}
```